# Proper macro for BOOL CDialog::OnCommand(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc, dialog

I'm porting to VS2017 an application previously compiled with VS6. Here's a piece of code that doesn't compile:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CVBindings, CDialog)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CVBindings)
   ON_COMMAND( IDC_BALT, OnCommand )
   ON_COMMAND( IDC_BCONTROL, OnCommand )
   // ...
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

The compiler error is:

```
error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'BOOL (__thiscall CVBindings::* )(WPARAM,LPARAM)' to 'AFX_PMSG'
note: None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
```

The function is declared as:

```
class CVBindings : public CDialog {
    // ...
    virtual BOOL OnCommand(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    // ...
};
```

This declaration matches the signature of `CWnd::OnCommand` so to override it.

However, it seems that I need to use other macro than `ON_COMMAND` . Could you suggest which one and how to use it? (I'm not familiar with MFC at all)

UPDATE: as requested in the comments, below are the pieces of the definition for `CVBindings::OnCommand`:

```
BOOL CVBindings::OnCommand(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    // ...
    // Some logic using just LOWORD(wParam), returning TRUE in some cases
    // ... 
    // Otherwise
    return CDialog::OnCommand(wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: `OnCommand` now returns `void` (see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f337825c-22f4-4aeb-8b30-96e96aa1f51e/error-c2440-staticcast-cannot-convert-bool-thiscall-cmainframe-void-to-afxpmsg?forum=vcgeneral).

Comment: @Jarod42 , no, it's not enough to just change the return type to `void`. It has to take `void` as parameters, but the code I'm porting needs at least the first parameter.

Comment: `CWnd::OnCommand` is virtual. You can simply override it and do your own dispatch; you don't need any message map entry for that. If you want to use `ON_COMMAND` macro in message map, the handler must take no parameters and return `void`. There's also `ON_COMMAND_EX` - the handler for that takes `UINT` command ID as its single parameter, and returns `BOOL`.

Comment: Show the definition for `OnCommand`. Is this simply responding to button clicks? Just use `ON_COMMAND` or `ON_COMMAND_EX` and fix the function definitions. In the unlikely case that you really need `WPARAM/LPARAM` then use `ON_MESSAGE(WM_USER + 1, foo) -> LRESULT xxx::foo(WPARAM, LPARAM)`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani , please, see my updated question.

Comment: That's still very little information. You want to comment out `ON_COMMAND( IDC_BALT, OnCommand )` and `ON_COMMAND( IDC_BCONTROL, OnCommand )` Add `ON_COMMAND(IDC_BCONTROL, OnBControl)`... with `void OnBControl(){...}`